# User interface optimization when using pack

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code, which creates an UI like this.
[image]

I want those page up/down buttons to be next to Page 1 label but I couldn't managed to do that. Only way I know with `pack` is the `side` option and it is not working well.

Second thing is, that scrollbar should be in that listbox. I know, I need to create a canvas then a frame in it. Then embed both listbox and scrollbar to them but I couldn't do that either.

This is my code.

```
class interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,den):
        self.pa_nu = 0  ##page number. Both used in labeling and result slicing
        self.lbl1 = tk.Label(den, text="keyword")
        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(den, text="Page %d" %(self.pa_nu+1))
        self.ent1 = tk.Entry(den, takefocus=True)
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(den, text="Search", command=self.button1)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(den, text="Page Up", command=self.page_up)
        self.btn3 = tk.Button(den, text="Page Down", command=self.page_down)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(den)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.lst1 = tk.Listbox(den, selectmode="SINGLE", width="40", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.lst1.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.open_folder)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.lst1.yview)

        self.lbl1.pack(side="top")
        self.ent1.pack()
        self.btn1.pack(side="top")
        self.btn2.pack(side="right")
        self.btn3.pack(side="left")
        self.lbl2.pack(side="bottom",padx=65)
        self.lst1.pack(fill=BOTH)

    def button1(self):     
        pass #some stuff here

    def page_up(self):
        pass #some stuff here

    def page_down(self):
        pass #some stuff here

    def list_fill(self,i):
        pass #some stuff here

    def open_folder(self,event):
        pass #some stuff here
```

Comment: As a side question, would it be better if I asked those two questions separetaly, or asking like this is ok?

Comment: for your first problem,use [grids](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: Two questions have to be asked separately. However, both yours deals with the layout of the same application so is acceptable in one post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three geometry managers in tkinter: place (absolute position), pack (good for line of widgets, or simple layout) and grid (complex layout).

[Grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) is worth looking for the layout you are working on. If you keep going with pack, the usual way to achieve complex layout is to use intermediate frames. For instance, in the following picture, all widgets in frame1 are packed vertically, and horizontally in frame2.

[image]
<sup>diagram with [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)</sup>

Regarding the scrollbar, the usual way is again to use an intermediate frame (no need for a canvas). Here a snippet (copied from http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm#listbox)

```
frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(frame, bd=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.pack()

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

frame.pack() #or others...
```